# How to break a while true statement

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming

I'm a beginner in Pytnon Networking . I'm writing this program in which a server will print whatever the client writes on his side. I don't know how to break the while statement in the best way if the client terminates the connection.

```
from socket import *


host = gethostname()
port = 27000
svr = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
svr.bind((host, port))
svr.listen(1)

print "Waiting for client connection..."
print "..."

c, addr = svr.accept()
print 'Got connection from', addr

while True:
    print c.recv(1024)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)? Twisted has some very nice features that will let you do this, for example my server which just parrots back what it hears:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class Echo(LineReceiver):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Client connection lost. Reason:\n{r}\n'.format(r=reason)
        LineReceiver.connectionLost(self, reason)
        reactor.stop()

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Sockets are nice at a very low level but sometimes a little too basic...

to get you off into Twisted world consider reading: http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this. it works. Hope you got this point.

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("Some bla bla':")
    if n.strip() == 'hello':
        break
```

Comment: thank you raj, I understand this point. But it's not exactly what I'm talking about. There are actually 2 different programs, one which is client and another one which is server (the one printed here). After the connection is made I want only the client to terminate the connection. But in the server side, the program doesn't terminate well, the while-loop keeps running...I was wondering if there was some statements I can add to perform a good ending too in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I would just try something like this

```py
while True:
   userInput = #here you insert whatever your user entered
   if userInput == "Insert break statement here": #you could insert here something like "I want to get out of this function" or something like that, so that user wouldn't just accidentally type it
      break
   else:
      print(userInput)
```